# file_exists returns false even when the path is right

Tags: php, wordpress, file-exists

I have seen some similar questions here, but no answer fit my needs.

I have a Wordpress and in the upload dir there is an image, I have the following url for the image: `../../uploads/2016/2/56c3620a9c8af.png` I try to access the file from inside the child theme folder:

`/home/mydomain/www/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen_child`

I would like to check if the file exists and afterwards `unlink()` the image, but the `file_exists` always returns `false`, even though I can echo the image.
The following simple function outputs the image but returns `false`.

```
function checkImageExist($url)
{
    echo '<img src = "'.$url.'" /><br>'; //The image is rendered

    clearstatcache();

    if(file_exists($url))
    {
       echo 'Image exists '.$url;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Image does not exist';    
    }
}
```

And this is what I CAN'T UNDERSTAND.
What am I missing?

THERE WAS NO QUESTION AT ALL:

The script I was using to upload the files was duplicating the extension names, so 56c3620a9c8af.png was in fact 56c3620a9c8af.png.png this stupid mistake was the responsible of images appearing when called (as the browser was able to parse them even though the duplicated extension) but file_exists was not able to find them.
So everything was working and I was mistaken about the error source.

Comment: try and avoid using relative paths. Also, to answer what you are missing, it is a backslash to escape the word `doesn\'t` :)

Comment: that's not your real ode, it has a syntax error

Comment: Yeah, I have translated to english and that's why the 'doesn't' is there...

Comment: I suggest you to search for the wp function to delete files, because if you manually delete-it, in db remains a record with filepath.

Comment: No, it is not. Upload directory is inside wp-content directory.

Comment: What is the full path to the file?

Comment: /home/mydomain/www/wp-content/uploads/2016/2/56c3620a9c8af.png

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a $url when what you really need is a $path. You can get the path like this:

```
$path = wp_upload_dir(); //This returns an array with URL info

$path['path']. '/2016/2/56c3620a9c8af.png'
```

Comment: Tried this:

    $updir = wp_upload_dir();

    checkImageExist($updir['basedir'].'/2016/2/56c3620a9c8af.png');

    Doesn't work.